# Как закинуть на репозиторий GItLab файлы и папки?

Tags: git, gitlab

Помогите с проблемой. Зарегистрировался на gitlab проекте. В https://gitlab.com входит под логином и паролем созданным мною. Однако потом я создаю папку-репозиторий для будущего проекта. Пытаюсь локальный репозиторий скопировать на сервер, выполняю сначала настройки глобального юзера и почты.

```
git config --global user.name "Андрей Ковалев"
git config --global user.email "al@studio.ru"
```

Затем выполняю пункты по добавлению файлов и создаю первый коммит на сайте. Дальше при команде push требует пароль.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Я ввожу его такой же, как от аккаунта на https://gitlab.com. Ругается, говорит неверный пароль. Как пройти проверку пароля и вообще по возможности избавиться от пароля когда я пушу или клонирую проект?

Comment: Зайдите в профиль на гитлабе, в раздел SSH Keys, и укажите свой открытый ключ SSH. Если у вас нет ssh-ключа, то метод его создания зависит от используемой операционной системы.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, операционка винда 11.

Comment: А что показывает `git remote -v`?

Comment: устанавливаете [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) и создаёте свой ssh ключ

Comment: Для windows удобнее всего puttygen из состава putty. Закрытый и открытый ключи лучше всего сохранить в папку %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\ там git их сам найдёт.

Comment: @AlexeyTen git remote -v показывает origin  git@gitlab.nostudio.ru:alarionov/renttorg_laravel.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.nostudio.ru:alarionov/renttorg_laravel.git (push)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Зачем ключ создавать? и устанавливать putty? Мне надо просто через консоль git отправить на сервер gitlab данные

Comment: пару лет назад git отказался от использования простой парольной защиты. Он принимает только SSH подключения.